# How to access response Body after simulating a POST request in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, http-post, reddit

I have been trying this out for a long time now.
I want to scrap contents from a subreddit that has adult contents.
But, the problem is that, you have to answer a simple question before you are given access to that page i.e. if you are 18+ or not. 
I did some research on the source code and found that the solution is a simple POST request. where you need to send the parameters "over18=yes".
But my problem is that, I am not able to access the response body after the post.

Here's the code using http request in node. I have even tried it out with the node "request" module, but no help from that either.

Hoping to find someone who can help me out here.

```
var http = require("http");


var options = {
  host: 'www.reddit.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/over18?dest=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2Fnsfw&over18=yes',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

And here is the code using the Node Request module

```
var request = require("request");
request.post({url:'http://www.reddit.com/over18?dest=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2Fnsfw', form: {over18:'yes'}}, function(err,httpResponse,body){
    console.log(body);
});
```

the URL i am trying to access is http://www.reddit.com/r/nsfw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, when you click YES button, the form sends *over18=yes* parameter to url *http://www.reddit.com/over18?dest=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2Fnsfw* using POST method. Then, server responds with an 302 Redirection header, cookie with value *over18=1* and finally redirects to url *http://www.reddit.com/r/nsfw* using GET request. THen, server just checks if youa have a cookie with needed valuse.

All what you need is to do request directly to the final url with cookies using GET method.

```
var request = require("request");

var target = "http://www.reddit.com/r/nsfw";

var jar = request.jar();
var cookie = request.cookie("over18=1");
cookie.domain = "reddit.com";
cookie.path = "/";

jar.setCookie(cookie, target, function(error, cookie) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(cookie);
});

request({
    uri: target,
    method: "GET",
    jar: jar
}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: This is perfect. A Big help and very educational. Didn't know we could send cookies like that. Thank you so much. People like u make this community a better place. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I too ran into this while *ahem* doing some research.. Here's my version:

```
var url = 'http://www.reddit.com/r/nsfw/';
var request = require('request');
request = request.defaults({jar: true });
request.post({
    followAllRedirects: true,
    url: 'http://www.reddit.com/over18?dest=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
    form: {uh: '', over18: 'yes', }
}, function(err, httpResponse, html) {
    …
});
```

Also worth a try are [Reddit's Node.js APIs](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API-Wrappers), of which I personally liked [Snoocore](https://github.com/trevorsenior/snoocore).

Comment: This is much shorter and simpler that the First answer ... and works perfectly fine. Thank you so much. Sorry I can only "accept" one answer here. I hope you don't mind. Thank you for looking into it ... Big Help.